# ¿como obtengo la versión dark y light de un color dado?

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, lógica

Bueno el problema es que estoy creando una aplicación, web la cual permite cambiar el color del tema desde la configuración, y me gustaria poder generar automáticamente las variantes dark y light de dicho color. Como lo hace esta página:

https://material.io/resources/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=F4511E&secondary.color=9C27B0

No tengo ningún avance de código que mostrar, porque no se me ocurre ningún algoritmo para lograrlo. su ayuda se agradece mucho.

Estoy trabajando con javascript. Aunque lo que me interesa es conocer la lógica que se aplica para sacar de un color sus versiones dark y light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no estoy equivocado, material.io usa la librería [Chroma.js](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) para generar las versiones oscuras y claras de los colores mediante los métodos `darken()` y `brighten()`.